# VLOOKUP & COUNTIF

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif

I'm looking for some help on trying to combine functions.

I think I need VLOOKUP & COUNTIF.

I have Sheet 1 with a list of clients, column A, I then have 12 other tabs Jan-Dec same table format on each, client listed in column C.

On sheet 1, I want to count from every month tab how many times listed (invoices sent)
Not every client in the list will appear on the month invoice tabs , others more than once.

[Please see screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfs3C.png)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you 
Amy

Answer (score 1):

You only need CountIf. Just reference the client on Sheet 1:-

`=countif(January!C3:C100, Sheet1!A3)`. Copy this down to reference the client on each row.

You could also consider the following for a better working and easier spreadsheet:-

-Define ranges and reference those instead
-Copy all your monthly data with the year into one sheet. Have a column for month and year then just autofilter to get the month you want - using countif to also reference the month and year if you just want a particular one in question

You'll find it easier to grown your spreadsheet and build formulae if your data is tidy and less dispersed.

Hope this helps,

Phil

Comment: Hi Phil, Thank you this is what I had formulated before but it only counts from Jan tab and I wanted to get it to count from every tab JAN - DEC if possible as a client breakdown? Thank you again

Comment: Yes - extend the range to cover all the sheets, ```=countif(January!C3:C100, February!C3:C100, Sheet1!A3)``` and so on. It's easier if you create a range first by using Ctrl to select multiple areas across the sheets and then name them in the cell address bar (to left of the formula bar). You can also use "define name" which should be in the formula menu.

Comment: It's all in the range Amy. Get your range set up correctly and you should be able to just reference that ```countif(myrange, "someclient")```

Comment: Hero!! Thank you .

Comment: oh, I'm getting #VALUE! show up instead of the number counted....

Comment: post your formula, it's not happy with it

Comment: =COUNTIF(ClientCount,A3)

Comment: @Amy the range cannot be disconnected in the COUNTIF.  You will need to do a countif for each tab and add them together.